# Node.js How to compare two streams?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, node.js-stream

I am reading many files that contain a mixture of objects. I have one `root` stream that streams objects like:

```
// root stream
{"action": "action_type_a", "id": "1234"}
{"action": "action_type_b", id: "24566"}
{"action": "action_type_b", id: "0808098"}
{"action": "action_type_b", id: "8098098"}
{"action": "action_type_a", "id": "098098"}
{"action": "action_type_b", id: "08098"}
```

I pipe the `root` stream into 2 separate `grep` filtered streams one filtering for `action_type_a` that we'll call `A` and looks like:

```
// stream A
{"action": "action_type_a", "id": "1234"}
{"action": "action_type_a", "id": "098098"}
```

and one filtering for `action_type_b` `B` that looks like:

```
// stream B
{"action": "action_type_b", id: "24566"}
{"action": "action_type_b", id: "0808098"}
{"action": "action_type_b", id: "8098098"}
{"action": "action_type_b", id: "08098"}
```

I also have a seperate `map` of ids

```
// id map
{
 "1234" : "098098",
 ""098098" : "8098098"
}
```

so ids on `A` objects can match up with ids on `B` objects

I want to process stream `A` compare each objects id to the map and then process `B` to see if there is a corresponding object in stream `B`

I"m not sure how to handle this without draining stream `B` before processing every object in `A`.

My first thought was to clone `B` for each entry in `A`. Is that possible?

my current attempt is to use `event-streams` `es.map` on stream `A` and inside of the map function i'm attempting to read `B` and compare it with `A` and a I read `B` I also write to record back to `B`. This however is giving me the :

`(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.`

error because I am re-defining the listeners for `B` within the map of `A`

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense to me.  A stream is a stream, not a collection.  When you say that each object in stream A may have a corresponding object in stream B, what do you mean exactly?  Can you describe the whole problem?  It sounds like there might be a better way.

Comment: @Brad I tried to flesh it out a bit more let me know if that helps

Comment: Can you make sure both streams are sorted by `id`? If so you could do a sort of merge-sort, reading each stream exactly once, processing on-the-fly.

Comment: @kevzettler I don't think this is something you should be doing with streams.  You should take the output of your streams to some collection, and do any data work there.

Comment: @NitzanShaked no they cannot be sorted.

Comment: @Brad the amount of items really large and not constant loading them into collections in memory could take a long long time.

Comment: @kevzettler Then, what do you expect to compare?  You're saying you want to see if there is any instance of something in one collection in the other... but how could you possibly search through all of them without searching through all of them?  This question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @kevzettler: the streams are *produced* somewhere. Are they produced at run-time, or are simply read from disk? If read from disk, then they were once written. Can you index them?